What exactly is the use of all the annotations in apex rest class
Apologies if this sounds too noob but am trying to understand what exactly is the used of all the annotations like @HttpGet,@HttpPost,@HttpDelete,@HttpPut and @HttpPatch in apex rest class. The definition says that @HttpGet is for retrieving records, @HttpPost is for inserting a record, @HttpPatch is for updating a record and so on...
However, I tested and can do all operations like insert,update,upsert,delete,return a value all in @HttpPost method itself in apex rest class.
Would be great help if anyone could explain when to use which annotation, when all CRUD operations can be done in a single method itself with any of the annotations.

Salesforce won't enforce what you can do with the different methods. It's up to you. I'd recommend reading about best practice in REST API design, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/

You can misuse HTTP request methods in your REST service. There's nothing really preventing that. When to use which method is not really specific to Salesforce, and I would treat MDN as the ultimate source of truth: Http request methods. I'll just post the snippets here you asked about, and certainly not all methods are supported with Apex REST.

GET
The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.
POST
The POST method submits an entity to the specified resource, often causing a change in state or side effects on the server.
DELETE
The DELETE method deletes the specified resource.
PUT
The PUT method replaces all current representations of the target resource with the request payload.
PATCH
The PATCH method applies partial modifications to a resource.

